# Scroll mouse -> scroll up screen instead browse history

Tags: kubuntu, zsh

I'm new with Z-Shell, I got a problem that when I scroll my mouse, it shows me the zsh-history, but what I really wanna is to scroll up the screen, just like I drag the scrollbar on the side. seems by default mouse wheel is also mapped just like up/down key `^[[A` and `^[[B` on the keyboard.

Any idea how to congiure it?

Thanks.

Comment: Scrolling is a feature of the terminal emulator, therefore it would be helpful to know which one you use. Also, which version of kubuntu are you using?